# Why doesn't file->private_data return your context data?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

I'm reading the De Los Rios book on Linux Kernel Driver development and hit the container_of macro.

I get the fact that if I want to keep context data:

```
struct myContextData_t { 
   ... myData ...
   struct miscdevice misc; 
   ... more myData... 
};
```

I can then:

```
  myContextData = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev, sizeof(struct myContextData_t), GFP_KERNEL);
  .. set data in misc ..
  ret_val = misc_register(&myContextData->misc);
```

And when a read function gets called:

```
 static ssize_t read(struct file *file, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
 {
    ...
    // file->private_data points to &myContextData->misc, not to &myContextData, so figure out 
    // where myContextData is 
    myContextData = container_of(file->private_data, struct myContextData_t, misc);
    ...
 }
```

What I'm trying to figure out is why can't I just register my private data when I register my device?
I.E. Why not something like:

```
struct myContext_t { 
    ... myPrivateData ...
}; 
struct myContext_t myContext; 

struct miscdevice myMiscDevice { 
   .minor = ...,
   .name = "mydevice",
   .fops = &myfops,
   .context = &myContext,
}
```

And then:

```
static ssize_t read(struct file *file, char __user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
   myContext_t myContext = (myContext_t *) file->privateData->context; 
}
```

Rather than having to figure out where my miscdevice data belongs in my structure and 'backtrack'? I realize container_of is a macro evaluated at compile time which will probably boil down to one subtract at runtime. Usually things like that are either deliberate to save space/managed memory entries or relics of prior decisions which weren't futureproofed and ended up propagating to avoid requiring rewrites. It also, I gather, requires a GNU-specific which isn't necessarily available in other compilers, making porting the kernel difficult. I'm just curious what the reasoning was in this case.

Comment: The question seems about the overall idea of `container_of` macro. In short: `container_of` allows you to have a misc device and its data **together**, in a single structure (`myContextData`), instead of splitting it into separate structures (`myMiscDevice` and `myContext`). This becomes more important, when you want to **allocate** a misc device on the heap: without `container_of` you need to allocate two structures, and correctly process possible failures in-between these allocations.

Comment: And what if you need to ship your misc device with only a **single integer**? Would you allocate a separate integer on the heap and store pointer to in in `.context` field? Or would you "encode" that integer to the `.context` field itself? Macro `container_of` could be implemented by any compiler with C11 support. But **encoding** of the integer value into field `.context` of type `void*` is much more Linux/gcc-specific.